# Integrate $\int\tan (x)\sin (ax)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int\tan (x)\sin (ax)dx$$
> If $a$ integer number

I used the wolfram.Alpha.com site to give me the following
[image]

How can I use this result if I need to compute some values by using a program in  visual basic.6

Can anyone simplify this integration to make it without complex parts

#### Hints:

When I take an integer value of $a$ the integration will become without complex parts.

Comment: I doubt that VB6 can evaluate this integral without using [numerical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration).

Comment: this is a typical question in complex analysis using residues, so I am not sure what you mean by avoiding complex parts

Comment: If you take any integer value of $a$ the integration will become without complex part.

Comment: @Integrator I need indefinite integral

Comment: @Ehegh Then you should use Mathematica instead of VB

Comment: You'd need to decide what you need - indefinite integral or some numeric values. This will change the method of solution drastically.

Comment: @Ruslan I need to make a program to the indefinite integral.

Comment: What does it mean? Does your program have to do symbolic integration and get the result similar to that of Wolfram|Alpha, or does it have to calculate something to the numbers?

Comment: My job needs to make a comparison between the exact integration values and the numerical values for many values of $a$

Comment: What is the range of $x$?

Comment: @Ruslan from $0$ to $1$

Comment: I think you'd have to implement "exact" integration as integration of series, and then take such number of terms that the value no longer changes. Of course, it looks more like a numeric procedure, but it seems the simplest if you don't want to implement/search for implementation of hypergeometric function of complex variables for VB.

Comment: For integer values of *a*, write $\sin(ax)$ as a polynomial in $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, then apply the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution).